# Why Aeson encodes () as empty array?

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

I am surprised to know that Aeson encodes `()` as empty array. What is reason behind such behaviour? I think `null` would be more natural, am I wrong?

```
*Main> encode ()
"[]"
```

Comment: Does it encode tuples as arrays?

Comment: Yes. Perhaps I'm understand now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ToJSON` instance for `()` is defined as:

```
instance ToJSON () where
    toJSON _ = emptyArray
    {-# INLINE toJSON #-}
```

Because generally, tuples are encoded as arrays:

```
instance (ToJSON a, ToJSON b) => ToJSON (a,b) where
    toJSON (a,b) = Array $ V.create $ do
                     mv <- VM.unsafeNew 2
                     VM.unsafeWrite mv 0 (toJSON a)
                     VM.unsafeWrite mv 1 (toJSON b)
                     return mv
```

(I think `null` doesn't make much sense; usually `null` represents a lack of value where there *could* be one, so in Haskell you'd use `Nothing`. In fact, `encode Nothing` returns `"null"`. `()` is just a 0-tuple, and this instance is more consistent with other tuples.)

Comment: The problem with `Nothing` is that you should specify meaningless type, you can't just write `Nothing`. I.e. `encode (Nothing :: Maybe Text)`. Thank you, it does make sense now.

Comment: Isn't it idiomatic to use `()` to represent lack of value, like in `IO ()`?

Comment: @lambdas Strictly speaking that's "lack of information", not "lack of a value". `()` is the type that contains only the single value `()`; thus it's the type of values that "contain no information". Thus `IO ()` is the type of I/O actions that when run *must* produce "no information" as a value (only relevant for their side effects). There is a type `Void` in a library that *doesn't have any values*. But `IO Void` would be the type of I/O actions that cannot succeed in finishing and producing a value (if they did, they would produce a value in the type `Void`, but there are no such values).

Comment: You actually couldn't! See, `Void` has *no* values at all. A function of type `Void -> a` can't return anything, because there's nothing you can pass it.

Comment: It is possible, if we don't care of `Void` argument and return `undefined`, but then it is easy to forgot this, use returned value and crash the program. I'll better not do so.

Comment: I mean it is possible to write `ToJSON _ = Null` and `FromJSON Null = undefined`.